# Returning a file and a JavaScript event with Django

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE:** Using [Philippe Bruneau's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122733/returning-a-file-and-a-javascript-event-with-django/31124972#31124972) (see below), I'm able to get the loading animation to disappear when the zip file is created. However, this method stops the zip file from being delivered to the user for download. Is there a way to have both happen? I could probably have a link show up for the user to click to download the file, but I'd really like the download to start automatically.

---

I'm currently writing an application that takes some API data, puts it into spreadsheets, and spits the spreadsheets out to the user in a zip file. All of that is working the way it's supposed to. Awesome.

This is my current response in views.py:

```
zip_file = open('locationsreport.zip', 'rb')
response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'locationsreport.zip'
return response
```

In my index.html file, I have a loading gif that shows up when the user submits the form that creates the zip file. I'd like to add a JavaScript event to the response in order to hide this gif when the zip file is returned to the user. I thought that would be formatted something like this: `response = HttpResponse("<script>$('.loader').hide();</script>")`. I've been looking around, and I can't seem to find a way to return both the file and the script. Is there a way to do so, or can you only return one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just test in your response template if the zip_file exists ?

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    context = {'zip_file':zip_file}
    return render(request, 'response.html', context)
```

Then in your response.html template :

```
{% if zip_file %}
<p>Zip loaded, sorry no gif !</p>
{% else %}
<script>My gif function</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Using that method, I'm able to make sure the zip file was created and have the loading animation disappear, but the zip file itself is not being delivered to the user (which, of the two actions, is the more important one). Do you know of a way to still spit the file out to the user while using the response you posted?

Comment: Maybe you could use javascript in your response.html template, with 'zip-file' as the argument of the function to spit out the file.